# Can sent/received chat history be accessed by an IOS 10 iMessage app extension?

Tags: ios10, ios-app-extension, imessage

This is a very basic iMessage app extension question.

I'm looking to see if it's possible for an iMessage app to access the chat history and parse previously sent/received text messages. I'm aware that they are stored in an SQL database on the device, but not sure if that data is accessible from an iMessage app extension.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not :)

This is a question of privacy, and such thing will never (in my opinion) be allowed by Apple. They clearly said that they were worried about users privacy. iMessage extension can't even access the names of participants...

The only messages you can access are :

- Those sent via your iMessage extension **AND** that were selected by
  the user.
- Those that are received by your app extension **AND** that were sent
  via your app

Meaning that even messages sent via your app won't be accessible that easily.